# Unable to install the DependencyAgent Azure VM extension

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-log-analytics, azure-oms

I have an environment with about a dozen VMs each of which has the Microsoft Monitoring Agent reporting to a central OMS Workspace. In addition, these VMs have the DependencyAgent installed.

Five of the VMs have the DependencyAgent extension reporting their state on the portal as "Provisioning succeeded" and I can see them in the Service Map workspace solution in Log Analytics. However, for some reason, the other six show the extension as "Transitioning".

When I log into one of those VMs and view the logs for the extension in 
`C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent.DependencyAgentWindows\9.6.2.1366`

I see:

> Execution Output: Start-Service : Failed to start service 'Microsoft
>   Dependency Agent (MicrosoftDependencyAgent)'

I try to manually start the service, but get "The Microsoft Dependency Agent service on Local Computer started an then stopped." and in the Event Viewer I see "The Microsoft Dependency Agent service entered the stopped state."

Any idea what I could possibly be doing wrong or where I can get additional logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DependencyAgent Azure VM Extension, it is currently available only in East US, West Europe, West Central US, and, soon, SE Asia. So you should make sure that you are in the right region.

For more details, see [Azure VM Extension for Dependency Agent](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msoms/2017/08/29/azure-vm-extension-for-dependency-agent/).

Comment: Yes, that's probably it! Should the line in the link provided read "Remember that while your VM can be in any region, Service Map is currently available only FOR LOG ANALYTICS LOCATED in East US, West Europe, West Central US, and, soon, SE Asia."? Because you don't specify the location of the Service Map individually, instead, you add it to the workspace. Also, any idea when it would be available in additional regions?

Comment: I would update or you could pay attention to the update of Microsoft document if it could be available in additional regions. So be patient to wait.